# uploading java application using google app engine java sdk

Tags: java, python, google-app-engine

I am trying to upload java application using google app engine via command line. I have typed email and password correctly but I got an unauthorized error message.

```
C:\j\bin>appcfg.cmd update facebook/https_www.facebook.com_login.php_login_attem
pt=1/war
Reading application configuration data...
Dec 10, 2011 2:45:39 AM com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppEngineWebXmlReader
 readAppEngineWebXml
INFO: Successfully processed facebook/https_www.facebook.com_login.php_login_att
empt=1/war\WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml
Dec 10, 2011 2:45:39 AM com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AbstractConfigXmlRead
er readConfigXml
INFO: Successfully processed facebook/https_www.facebook.com_login.php_login_att
empt=1/war\WEB-INF/web.xml
Beginning server interaction for confirm-account...
0% Created staging directory at: 'C:\DOCUME~1\prasad\LOCALS~1\Temp\appcfg3683113
221538013906.tmp'
5% Scanning for jsp files.
20% Scanning files on local disk.
Dec 10, 2011 2:45:41 AM com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppVersionUpload addFil
e
SEVERE: Invalid character in filename: www.facebook.com_login.php_login_attempts
=1.php
Dec 10, 2011 2:45:41 AM com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppVersionUpload addFil
e
SEVERE: Invalid character in filename: __static__/www.facebook.com_login.php_log
in_attempts=1.php
25% Initiating update.
Email: madushka.prasad@gmail.com
Password for madushka.prasad@gmail.com:
Email: madushka.prasad@gmail.com
Password for madushka.prasad@gmail.com:
Email: madushka.prasad@gmail.com
Password for madushka.prasad@gmail.com:

java.io.IOException: Error posting to URL: 
ersion/create?app_id=confirm-account&version=1&
401 Unauthorized
Must authenticate first.

Unable to update app: Error posting to URL: 
version/create?app_id=confirm-account&version=1&
401 Unauthorized
Must authenticate first.

Please see the logs [C:\DOCUME~1\prasad\LOCALS~1\Temp\appcfg9182114970567100400.
log] for further information.

C:\j\bin>appcfg.sh update facebook/https_www.facebook.com_login.php_login_attemp
t=1/war

C:\j\bin>appcfg.cmd update facebook/https_www.facebook.com_login.php_login_attem
pt=1/war
Reading application configuration data...
Dec 10, 2011 2:58:28 AM com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppEngineWebXmlReader
 readAppEngineWebXml
INFO: Successfully processed facebook/https_www.facebook.com_login.php_login_att
empt=1/war\WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml
Dec 10, 2011 2:58:28 AM com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AbstractConfigXmlRead
er readConfigXml
INFO: Successfully processed facebook/https_www.facebook.com_login.php_login_att
empt=1/war\WEB-INF/web.xml
Beginning server interaction for confirm-account...
0% Created staging directory at: 'C:\DOCUME~1\prasad\LOCALS~1\Temp\appcfg6669469
867917197838.tmp'
5% Scanning for jsp files.
20% Scanning files on local disk.
Dec 10, 2011 2:58:29 AM com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppVersionUpload addFil
e
SEVERE: Invalid character in filename: www.facebook.com_login.php_login_attempts
=1.php
Dec 10, 2011 2:58:29 AM com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppVersionUpload addFil
e
SEVERE: Invalid character in filename: __static__/www.facebook.com_login.php_log
in_attempts=1.php
25% Initiating update.
Email: madushka.prasad@gmail.com
Password for madushka.prasad@gmail.com:
Email: madushka.prasad@gmail.com
Password for madushka.prasad@gmail.com:
Email: madushka.prasad@gmail.com
Password for madushka.prasad@gmail.com:

java.io.IOException: Error posting to URL: 
ersion/create?app_id=confirm-account&version=1&
401 Unauthorized
Must authenticate first.

Unable to update app: Error posting to URL: 
version/create?app_id=confirm-account&version=1&
401 Unauthorized
Must authenticate first.

Please see the logs [C:\DOCUME~1\prasad\LOCALS~1\Temp\appcfg3311199412959094475.
log] for further information.
```

Comment: The message would tend to indicate you _haven't_ entered your password correctly. Are you using two-factor authentication?

Answer (score 2):

If you really have an app engine project in a directory named

```
facebook/https_www.facebook.com_login.php_login_attempt=1
```

then the first thing I'd try is renaming that to something that doesn't include an `=`.